# Can't build - expo buid:ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

When I tried `expo build ios`, I got an error.

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/spaceship1605177195_56585_70287563760080.log
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue."
Error: Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue."
    at runAction (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/fastlane.ts:28:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at authenticate (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/appleApi/authenticate.ts:49:40)
    at Context.ensureAppleCtx (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/credentials/context.ts:81:24)
    at IOSBuilder.bestEffortAppleCtx (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:95:14)
    at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:151:5)
    at IOSBuilder.run (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/ios/IOSBuilder.ts:62:7)
    at IOSBuilder.command (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:39:7)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/test/local/test/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:332:7)
```

This is the first time to build and my expo-cli version is the latest (3.28.5).

```
Expo CLI 3.28.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.15.5
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.8 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.5, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 11.5/11E608c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~39.0.2 => 39.0.3 
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz => 0.63.2 
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.28.5
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo expo build:ios
```

This command solved the issue.

I still don't know why it needs `sudo` though.